# Locus of the points on complex plane which ${\bf Re\,}z^n={\bf Im\,}z^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

> Locus of the points on complex plane which real and imaginary parts are equal:
>   $${\bf Re\,}z^n={\bf Im\,}z^n$$

Sketch the subsets of the Argand diagram:

$Re[(x+iy)^2]=Im[(x+iy)^2]$

$Re[(x+iy)^3]=Im[(x+iy)^3]$

---

The equation $Re[(x+iy)^2]=Im[(x+iy)^2]$ simplifies to $x^2-2xy-y^2=0$, or $x-y=\pm y\sqrt{2}$, so the picture contains two lines passing through $(0,0)$.

Similarily for the second one: $(x+y)(x^2-4xy+y^2)=0$, or $(x+y)(x-2y-y\sqrt{3})(x-2y+y\sqrt{3})=0$.

---

What about $Re[(x+iy)^n]=Im[(x+iy)^n]$ in general?

Does it give $n$ lines passing through $(0,0)$ as in particular cases?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried polar forms https://www.varsitytutors.com/hotmath/hotmath_help/topics/polar-form-of-a-complex-number and De Moivre https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
{\bf Re\,}z^n&={\bf Im\,}z^n\\
\dfrac{1}{2}(z^n+\bar{z}^n)&=\dfrac{1}{2i}(z^n-\bar{z}^n)\\
\left(\dfrac{z}{\bar{z}}\right)^n&=i\hspace{4cm}z=re^{i\theta}\\
e^{2in\theta}&=e^{i(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})}\hspace{2.6cm}k=0,1,\cdots,n-1\\
\theta&=\dfrac{k}{n}\pi+\frac{\pi}{4n}
\end{align}
shows all points $z$ with arbitrary $r\geq0$ and $\theta=\dfrac{4k+1}{4n}\pi$ which are $n$ rays from origin with $\theta=\dfrac{4k+1}{4n}\pi$ where $k=0,1,\cdots,n-1$.